# In my C program, why are my traced loop and actual output different?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, trace

1. Trace the execution of the following program? What will be the final values of array be printed?
   I have to trace the following C code and write the output. I ran the program and the output is different than what I expected. Most likely I traced it incorrectly but I can't find what I am doing wrong.

*I didn't write the code. The code was included in the question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int a[7]={2,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int i=1;

    for (i=1; i<7; i++)
    {

       if (i<3)
          a[i] = a[i-1]+i+1; //when i=1, a[1]= a[1-1]+1+1 -> a[0]+1+1 -> 2+1+1=4
                             //a[1] is now 4
                             //when i=2, a[2]= a[2-1]+1+1 -> a[1]+1+1 -> 4+2+1=7
                             //a[2] is now 7
       else if (i<5) 
          a[i] = a[i-2]+1;   //when i=3, a[3]= a[3-2]+1 -> a[1]+1 -> 4+1=6 
                             //a[3] is now 6 but it should be 11??? 11
                             //when i=4, a[4]= a[4-1]+1 -> a[2]+1 -> 7+1=8
                             //a[4] is now 8 but it should be 16??? 16

       else
          a[i] = a[i-2]*i-2; //when i=5, a[5]= a[5-2]*5-2 -> a[3]*3 -> 6*3= 18 
                             //a[5] is now 18 but it should be 22???
                             //when i=6, a[6]= a[6-1]*6-2 -> a[5]*4 -> 18*4= 72
                             //a[6] is now 8 but it should be 29????

    }
    for (i=0; i<7; i++)
       printf("a[%d] = %d\n",i,a[i]); //prints a[0] = 2 first because i=0 in the above loop
}
```

Actual Output:

```
a[0] = 2
a[1] = 4
a[2] = 7
a[3] = 11
a[4] = 16
a[5] = 22
a[6] = 29
```

Comment: *`4+1=6`* - What.

Comment: Where did you get your "actual output" from? That's not what I'm seeing.

Comment: additionally to the comments by melpomene above I noticed you wrote `//when i=6, a[6]= a[6-1]*6-2 -> a[5]*4 -> 18*4= 72` but it says `a[i] = a[i-2]*i-2;` so it should be `(a[4]*6)-2` with `a[4]` being `8`

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and ran it, this is my output：

```
a[0] = 2
a[1] = 4
a[2] = 7
a[3] = 5
a[4] = 8
a[5] = 23
a[6] = 46
```

Comment: You are right. I don't know what I did before. But still my tracing is wrong. The first 3 came out right but something went wrong from the second else if. Do you know what happened?

Comment: when i=3, a[3]= a[3-2]+1 -> a[1]+1 -> 4+1=5 
when i=4, a[4]= a[4-2]+1 -> a[2]+1 -> 7+1=8
when i=5, a[5]= a[5-2]*5-2 -> (a[3]*5)-2 -> (5*5)-2= 23
when i=6, a[6]= a[6-2]*6-2 -> (a[4]*6)-2 -> (8*6)-2= 46

Comment: you should do "*" and "/" before "+" and "-" if there is no parentheses